# boto3 client.get_log_events returns no events only when startFromHead is false

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to get logs from CloudWatch, and I'm interested in the first and the last log line, so I'm querying with both `startFromHead=True` (oldest to newest) and `startFromHead=False` (newest to oldest). However, when querying the same log, I get events when `startFromHead=True`, but not when `startFromHead=False`.

Here's some sample code, where I've defined the `logStreamName` and `logGroupName` elsewhere:

```
cw = boto3.client('logs')
cw.get_log_events(
    logGroupName=logGroupName,
    logStreamName=logStreamName,
    startFromHead=True,
    limit=1
)
# Returns the oldest log entry in the log stream
```

```
cw = boto3.client('logs')
cw.get_log_events(
    logGroupName=logGroupName,
    logStreamName=logStreamName,
    startFromHead=False,
    limit=1
)
# events key points to an empty list in the response, as though there are no events
```

I don't know why I'm not getting any results where `startFromHead=False`. What's more, it's not every log stream. The first stream in my group was fine, but the second showed this behavior. I tried iterating through the streams in the group, and all of them had this behavior except for the first.

Comment: Hi, I'm experiencing the same problem - did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue today. I used the `nextBackwardToken` included in the response and set that as the `nextToken` argument for a subsequent call to `get_log_events`.

Per the [docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/logs/client/get_log_events.html#:%7E:text=This%20token%20is%20not%20null.%20If%20you%20have%20reached%20the%20end%20of%20the%20stream%2C%20it%20returns%20the%20same%20token%20you%20passed%20in.) `nextBackwardToken` will never be null. Instead, when you reach the end of the stream the same token will be returned back to you.

This function will loop until that condition is met.

```
cw = boto3.client('logs')

def get_log_events(log_group, log_stream):
    events = dict()
    next_token = None

    params = dict(
        logGroupName=log_group,
        logStreamName=log_stream,
        startFromHead=False,
    )

    while next_token != events.get('nextBackwardToken', ''):
        next_token = events.get('nextBackwardToken')
        if next_token:
            params["nextToken"] = next_token
        
        events = cw.get_log_events(**params)

        for event in events.get('events'):
            yield event
```